# Mysql fulltext index search returning weird result

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have ingredient table. I want all those recipes which have certain ingredients. Below is my table structure.

```
Table(ingredient) - Applied fulltext index on ingredient column.
------------------------------------------------------
 ingredientID   rcteID  ingredient  
    310           1     Mint Leaves     
    311           1     Corriender Leaves   
    312           1     GreenChili
```

I am trying to fetch above record below fulltext search query but not getting that record.

```
SELECT `Ingredient`.`ingredientID` , `Ingredient`.`rcteID`
FROM `ingredient` AS `Ingredient`
WHERE MATCH (`Ingredient`.`ingredient`) 
      AGAINST ('+Mint Leaves +Corriender Leaves +Greenchili' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND `Ingredient`.`rcteID`
IN ( 1 )
GROUP BY `Ingredient`.`rcteID`
```

Why above query is not working for above record?

**When I tried below query it worked. just changed searching text.**

```
SELECT `Ingredient`.`ingredientID` , `Ingredient`.`rcteID`
FROM `ingredient` AS `Ingredient`
WHERE MATCH (`Ingredient`.`ingredient`) 
      AGAINST ('+Greenchili +Mint Leaves +Corriender Leaves' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND `Ingredient`.`rcteID` IN ( 1 )
GROUP BY `Ingredient`.`rcteID`

OUTPUT
--------------------
ingredientID    rcteID
311                1
```

Don't understand what's going on. Why first query not returning any result and below query returning result?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MySQL Documentation on FULLTEXT Boolean Searching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

> "
>
> A phrase that is enclosed within double quote (“"”) characters matches
>   only rows that contain the phrase literally, as it was typed. The
>   full-text engine splits the phrase into words and performs a search in
>   the FULLTEXT index for the words. Nonword characters need not be
>   matched exactly: Phrase searching requires only that matches contain
>   exactly the same words as the phrase and in the same order. For
>   example, "test phrase" matches "test, phrase".
>
> If the phrase contains no words that are in the index, the result is
>   empty. For example, if all words are either stopwords or shorter than
>   the minimum length of indexed words, the result is empty.
>
> The following examples demonstrate some search strings that use
>   boolean full-text operators:
>
> 'apple banana'
>
> Find rows that contain at least one of the two words.
>
> '+apple +juice'
>
> Find rows that contain both words.
>
> '+apple macintosh'
>
> Find rows that contain the word “apple”, but rank rows higher if they
>   also contain “macintosh”.
>
> '+apple -macintosh'
>
> Find rows that contain the word “apple” but not “macintosh”.
>
> '+apple ~macintosh'
>
> Find rows that contain the word “apple”, but if the row also contains
>   the word “macintosh”, rate it lower than if row does not. This is
>   “softer” than a search for '+apple -macintosh', for which the presence
>   of “macintosh” causes the row not to be returned at all.
>
> '+apple +(>turnover
>
> Find rows that contain the words “apple” and “turnover”, or “apple”
>   and “strudel” (in any order), but rank “apple turnover” higher than
>   “apple strudel”.
>
> 'apple*'
>
> Find rows that contain words such as “apple”, “apples”, “applesauce”,
>   or “applet”.
>
> '"some words"'
>
> Find rows that contain the exact phrase “some words” (for example,
>   rows that contain “some words of wisdom” but not “some noise words”).
>   Note that the “"” characters that enclose the phrase are operator
>   characters that delimit the phrase. They are not the quotation marks
>   that enclose the search string itself.

## MAIN PROBLEM

- You are searching for 3 ingredients
- You are querying for 4 words (`Mint, Leaves, Corriender, Greenchili`)

## COURSE OF ACTION

You need to adjust the MATCH clause to query three string tokens. You do that by putting double quotes around `"Mint Leaves"` and `"Corriender Leaves"`:

```
SELECT `Ingredient`.`ingredientID` , `Ingredient`.`rcteID`
FROM `ingredient` AS `Ingredient`
WHERE MATCH (`Ingredient`.`ingredient`) 
      AGAINST ('+Greenchili +"Mint Leaves" +"Corriender Leaves"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND `Ingredient`.`rcteID` IN ( 1 )
GROUP BY `Ingredient`.`rcteID`
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

NOTE: Corriender should be spelled [**Coriander**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriander)

Answer (score 0):

Plus sing means AND operator, - means NOT and space means OR operator. You are probably looking for MySQL to use "Mint Leaves" as a phrase while it takes you search request as "Mint OR Leaves" which leads to unexpected results. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

You are probably need to reconstruct your query to be something like "Mint AND Leaves" OR "Corriender AND Leaves" OR "Greenchili" which would be:

```
 "Mint +Leaves Corriender +Leaves Greenchili"
```

Or try external search engine that support phrase match like Solr or Sphinx