# mysql fulltext - exact match or nothing

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have mysql table with column tags, and would like to search exact match.
For this data:

```
 proj7 invoice delivery
 proj7 exchange
```

and this query

```
 MATCH(tags) AGAINST ('+proj7 +(invoice report)')
```

should be

```
 (proj7 AND (invoice OR report))
```

So i want only first record in result, but there are both, second with low score due to proj7 existence. How can i query exact matches only.

sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26524/3

Comment: It seems to me you might use separate table of tags. Check http://tagging.pui.ch/post/37027745720/tags-database-schemas and http://stackoverflow.com/a/334246/1786423

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PROPOSED QUERY

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE MATCH(tags)
AGAINST ('"+proj_7" "(invoice report)"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

## YOUR SAMPLE DATA LOADED

```
mysql> USE test
Database changed
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `test` (
    ->   `tags` text NOT NULL,
    ->   FULLTEXT KEY `tags` (`tags`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.20 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test (tags) VALUES ("proj_7 type_invdtl year_15 month_04");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test (tags) VALUES ("proj_8 type_invdtl year_15 month_04");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test (tags) VALUES ("proj_10 type_invdtl year_15 month_04");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+--------------------------------------+
| tags                                 |
+--------------------------------------+
| proj_7 type_invdtl year_15 month_04  |
| proj_8 type_invdtl year_15 month_04  |
| proj_10 type_invdtl year_15 month_04 |
+--------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## PROPOSED QUERY EXECUTED

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test WHERE MATCH(tags)
    -> AGAINST ('"+proj_7" "(invoice report)"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
+-------------------------------------+
| tags                                |
+-------------------------------------+
| proj_7 type_invdtl year_15 month_04 |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## OTHER EXAMPLES

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test WHERE MATCH(tags)
    -> AGAINST ('"+proj_7" "(type_invdtl year_15)"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
+--------------------------------------+
| tags                                 |
+--------------------------------------+
| proj_7 type_invdtl year_15 month_04  |
| proj_8 type_invdtl year_15 month_04  |
| proj_10 type_invdtl year_15 month_04 |
+--------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test WHERE MATCH(tags)
    -> AGAINST ('"+proj_7" "(type_invdt2 year_15)"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
+-------------------------------------+
| tags                                |
+-------------------------------------+
| proj_7 type_invdtl year_15 month_04 |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test WHERE MATCH(tags) AGAINST ('"+proj_7 +type_invdtl" "+proj_7 +year15"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
+-------------------------------------+
| tags                                |
+-------------------------------------+
| proj_7 type_invdtl year_15 month_04 |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test WHERE MATCH(tags) AGAINST ('"+proj_7 +type_invdtl" "+proj_7 +year16"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
+-------------------------------------+
| tags                                |
+-------------------------------------+
| proj_7 type_invdtl year_15 month_04 |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test WHERE MATCH(tags) AGAINST ('"+proj_7 +type_invdt2" "+proj_7 +year16"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: maybe i'm trying to do something, what is not possible in fulltext search... but if i search proj_7 AND (invoice OR report) ... result should not contain rows with proj_7 only .. 

in proposed query there is one row in result, but there is no "invoice" or "report" in that row, so i dont want this row

Comment: Added two more examples

Comment: Added three more examples (5 altogether)

Comment: yes, looking at last query you wrote, i can rewrite query "A AND (B OR C)" to "(A AND B) OR (A AND C)" so for this example it works.. but i have more complex query (i simplified it) what if i have "(A AND (B OR C) OR (D AND (E OR F OR G OR H))" .. i can't write queries using boolean logic? have to rewrite to all possibilities?

Comment: Most likely you will have to code the possibilities. See my old post http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84402/mysql-fulltext-index-search-returning-weird-result/84463#84463 where I quote from the MySQL Documentation.

Comment: thank you for your time! helped me identify problem.. have to switch fulltext to another engine sphinx or elastic